# Unity Virtual Reality SDK Failed to initialize?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok Im building for Oculus and Unity and I have everything working well on one PC in Unity 2018.0.2f2 and Oculus utilities 1.26.

I copied the project and opened it with the same version of Unity downloaded from the archives on another PC and when running (same Rift, everything) the game has the warning: `Virtual Reality SDK Failed to initialize` and the game runs, but not on the Rift.

Ive tried everything I can think of - I get the "Do you want to Update from 1,26 to 1.27" regarding Oculus Utilities, and did so because that may be the problem, but updating to 1.27 and restarting does nothing.

How can I fix this? The forums aren't very helpful